# My nodemon app crashed after updating npm. What to do?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, npm-update

I went ahead and used `npm update` in my terminal(hyper) and when I tried to restart my `app.js` server, I got an error stating

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

I thought I needed to use this command (`npm update`) in order to update my node modules, but then for some reason, some modules got deleted. (`"Error: Cannot find module 'parseurl'`"). I'm still a newbie to development and have no clue where to go from here. What to do?

Here's a screenshot of the error in my terminal.
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMjnr.jpg)

Comment: Please include screenshots in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon tried to start the server, but it won't start successfully if it can't find the module you are referencing.  Try reinstalling "parseurl" `npm i parseurl` and make sure the path to the module is correct.  Once you have done that, the server should start successfully pending any other issues.